# JQL for getting all epics related to an epic and all stories created under that epic

Tags: jira, jql

What I'm trying to do.
We have board which contains an Epic. Lets say the key of this epic is "MY-01".
Now, I have another epic on a different board with key : "AOB-01".
Under epic "AOB-01" I have created story: AOB-03 and AOB-04.

Now I want a JQL which gives me all issues related to MY-01 AND the children of all issues created under that link.

I have used:
issue in linkedIssues(MY-01, "relates to") to get all epics under MY-01.

Then I have:
issue in childIssuesOf("AOB-01") to get all stories (in this case AOB-03 and AOB-04).

But I cannot get a JQL which combines these two.
Can anyone help me out?

Regards,
Barry

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine 2 JQL queries you can use the operator "AND":

```
issue in linkedIssues(MY-01, "relates to") AND issue in childIssuesOf("AOB-01")
```